# Как получить чистый список процессов службы systemd?

Tags: linux, systemd

```
$ systemctl status webapp
● webapp.service - uWSGI Web Application
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/webapp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-08-05 02:43:28 EEST; 4 weeks 1 days ago
 Main PID: 75691 (uwsgi)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 2218)
   CGroup: /system.slice/webapp.service
           ├─75691 /usr/bin/uwsgi --ini uwsgi.conf
           ├─86724 /usr/bin/uwsgi --ini uwsgi.conf
           ├─86725 /usr/bin/uwsgi --ini uwsgi.conf
           └─86726 /usr/bin/uwsgi --ini uwsgi.conf
```

Я хочу получить отсюда только числа `75691 86724 86725 86726`, чтобы в дальнейшем работать с ними. Как это можно красиво сделать? Обмазываться grep/sed/awk не хочется, должны же быть какой-нибудь нормальный API или опции у команды systemctl?

Comment: (Я знаю, что конкретно uWSGI сам может отдать список своих воркеров через JSON, но меня интересует более общий случай.)

Comment: В сторону `pgrep` смотрели?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eri в [соседнем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1027416) напомнил мне, что у systemd вообще-то есть D-Bus API, так что получить список процессов можно обращением к методу `org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager.GetUnitProcesses`:

```
$ dbus-send --system --print-reply \
    --dest=org.freedesktop.systemd1 \
    /org/freedesktop/systemd1 \
    org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager.GetUnitProcesses \
    string:"webapp.service"

method return time=1569360100.695930 sender=:1.179 -> destination=:1.194 serial=9339 reply_serial=2
   array [
      struct {
         string "/system.slice/webapp.service"
         uint32 127901
         string "/usr/bin/uwsgi --ini uwsgi.conf"
      }
      struct {
         string "/system.slice/webapp.service"
         uint32 127910
         string "/usr/bin/uwsgi --ini uwsgi.conf"
      }
   ]
```

Форматирования вывода у `dbus-send` я не нашёл, но в принципе уже отсюда можно грепнуть `uint32`, но я не люблю грепать что попало.

Себе я накатал Python-скрипт:

```py
import sys
from pydbus import SystemBus

bus = SystemBus()
r = bus.get("org.freedesktop.systemd1")
for x in r.GetUnitProcesses(sys.argv[1]):
    print(x[1])
```

И вот уже он печатает только числа:

```
$ python ./get_service_pids.py webapp.service
127901
127910
```

Answer (score 0):

У systemctl такой возможности нет. На мой взгляд будет красивее работать с выводом `ps -ef`

Answer (score 0):

Как то так можно:

```
systemctl status | grep -o -E  '─([0-9]+)\ '
```

Нужно только избавиться от дефиса в начале строки.

Обратите внимание:

1. Первый символ в регулярном выражении - символ псевдографики "горизонтальная черта", а не "минус".
2. Перед завершающим апострофом стоит пробел.