# Настройка доступа в systemd loginctl

Tags: linux, systemd

Этот наш новомодный systemd палит посторонним пользователям все мои секретики:

```
guest@andreymal:~$ loginctl session-status 32757
32757 - andreymal (1000)
           Since: Wed 2019-09-04 02:09:11 MSK; 2 weeks 5 days ago
          Leader: 2535
          Remote: 127.0.0.1
         Service: sshd; type tty; class user
           State: closing
            Unit: session-32757.scope
                  ├─19648 SCREEN -dmS supersecret bash -c ./secretprogram.py --password correcthorsebatterystaple
                  ├─19649 bash -c ./secretprogram.py --password correcthorsebatterystaple
                  └─19650 ./secretprogram.py --password correcthorsebatterystaple
```

С какого перепугу посторонний пользователь, не являющийся администратором, может читать чужие сессии? Есть ли у systemd-logind (да и у systemd в целом вообще) где-нибудь настройки доступа к подобным вещам? <s>Или это такой хитрый план у Поттеринга заставить всех переходить на контейнеры?</s>

Comment: На случай, если кто-то скажет «дык ведь в /proc всё и так видно» — я его прикрыл через hidepid=2, так что не видно :)

Comment: контейнеры тоже палятся в proc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае `loginctl` делает опрос systemd(который ==инит и имеет все права) по dbus

```
sudo dbus-monitor --system | grep -A 20 -B4  org.freedesktop.systemd1
```

:

```
method call time=1569283475.818053 sender=:1.10522 -> destination=org.freedesktop.systemd1 serial=5 path=/org/freedesktop/systemd1; interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager; member=GetUnitProcesses
   string "session-2.scope"
method return time=1569283475.829297 sender=:1.0 -> destination=:1.10522 serial=8818 reply_serial=5
   array [
      struct {
         string "/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-2.scope"
         uint32 704
         string "gdm-session-worker [pam/gdm-password]"
      }
      struct {
         string "/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-2.scope"
         uint32 726
         string "/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login"
      }
      struct {
         string "/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-2.scope"
         uint32 730
```

Разграничивать доступ к методам можно в файле `/usr/share/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.systemd1.conf` (такой поставляется разработчиками дистрибутива):

```
    <policy context="default">
            <deny send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"/>
            .....
            .....
            <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                   send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                   send_member="GetUnitProcesses"/>
```

Там ещё много методов, которые могут показать список процессов. Удалите это разрешение и списка процессов в выводе команды не будет.

В `polkit-1` ничего интересного на эту тему нет.

Лучший вариант спрятать секрет такого плана это поместить его в файл.

Comment: К сожалению, существуют такие программы, которые не позволяют помещать секреты ни в файл, ни даже в переменную окружения, и по умолчанию не в моих силах это изменить (например, 7z и ffmpeg)

Comment: А это откуда такой любопытный вывод в первом сниппете? Про dbus я в курсе, а вот нормально мониторить его ещё не научился

Comment: добавил как запускал монитор в ответ